# FSO multiple wildcards for folder path

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to add also a wildcard in the folder path? There are 4 levels of folders. 
 Main_folder: path is known 
 Subfolders 1: foldername is partially known. In my example *4*. There is a folder 4.1 and 4.2(also 5.1, 5.2, 6.1 and 6.2)  but I don`t know where the files will end up 
 subfolders 2: path is known 
 subfolders 4: here are the folders located that I need to copy.

```
FSO.copyfolder "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\retrieve test\New folder\4*\*" & wb.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B1") & "*", "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\retrieve test\Lay\Lay"
```

Below example works to copy the correct folders but here is my third folder defined (this should be variable)

```
FSO.copyfolder "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\retrieve test\New folder\4.1\*" & wb.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B1") & "*", "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\retrieve test\Lay\Lay"
```

What the macro needs to do is loop through all the folders to find the partial name that is defined in B1 on sheet 3.

[image]

Comment: "In the folder path", definitely not.  But, yes, when you use a string in order to look for. I am afraid you cannot avoid iteration and it would be better (I thing) to use `If InStr("folderName", "5.1") Or `InStr("folderName", "5.2") etc. Then`...

Comment: if all the subfolders will need to be looped through regardless of contents, you can do recursive looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer was based on my misunderstanding and file. This has been modified so that if there are multiple files in each folder, the same folder name is duplicated, so only a unique single folder is extracted and the folder is copied to the destination folder.

```
Option Explicit

Dim vR()
Dim n As Long
Sub copyFileFromFolder()

    Dim strFolder As String, TargetFolder As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vSplit
    Dim str As String, Path As String
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim FS As Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Set FS = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    strFolder = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\retrieve test\New folder\"
    TargetFolder = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\retrieve test\Lay\Lay\"

    '*** The folder address below is for my test.
    'strFolder = "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\"                 '<~~ for my test -->It corresponds to  your New folder
    'TargetFolder = "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\target\"       '<~~ for my test

    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    str = Wb.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B1")

    SearchFolder strFolder
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To n
        Path = vR(i)
        Path = Replace(Path, strFolder, "")
        vSplit = Split(Path, "\")
        If UBound(vSplit) = 2 Then
            If InStr(vSplit(2), str) Then
                FS.CopyFolder vR(i), TargetFolder & vSplit(2)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    '** Show Root folder's subfolders

    With Sheets.Add ' set Sheets("your sheets's name)
        .UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents
        .Range("a2").Resize(n) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End With
    Erase vR
    n = 0
End Sub
Sub SearchFolder(strRoot As String)
    Dim FS As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fsFD As Folder
    Dim f As Folder
    Dim p As String

    On Error Resume Next
    p = Application.PathSeparator
    If Right(strRoot, 1) = p Then
    Else
        strRoot = strRoot & p
    End If
    Set FS = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Set fsFD = FS.GetFolder(strRoot)
    For Each f In fsFD.SubFolders
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
        With f
            vR(n) = f.Path
        End With
        SearchSubfolder f
    Next f

    Set fsFD = Nothing
    Set FS = Nothing

End Sub
Sub SearchSubfolder(objFolder As Folder)
    Dim sbFolder As Object
    Dim f As Folder
    For Each sbFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        SearchSubfolder sbFolder
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
        vR(n) = sbFolder.Path
    Next sbFolder

End Sub
```

### Destination folder image

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code. I cant get it to work. First I have an error on 
`Sub SearchSubfolder(colFile As Collection, objFolder As folder)`
Compile error: User defined type not defined.
If I delete this sub, there are errors on the object scripting lines so I changed them to

`CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`

Then I get errors on the 'dim as folders, same compile error. Is it possible that it doens`t recognize folder?

Comment: I changed al the `as folder and file` to `object' I also put a few remarks in your code to clarify what I can see

Comment: @Wesley, reference check,  Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Comment: It was unchecked, If I now change it to the original code it will not give an error but doesn't copy the folders

Comment: Is it possible to explain the code a little bit? I've put debug.prints all over the code but still cannot figure out how it is working. There are also no values returning in the `for each fsFD.files` and `for each f in sbFolder.Files`. If I'm able to understand, I might be able to change the code to my needs

Comment: @welsey,  I think I misunderstood. I worked on the file name.

Comment: I was wondering why you were using the .File but since I did not understand the code completely I thougt it would be like that. I already get a list of all folder paths with your code so mayby I can work with that :)

Comment: I see now what it is doing, it searches the file name inside a folder and copies that folder. The problem is that there are no files that have the name from the range in cell B1 all the files created in the folder are with date and time. Only the folder itself has the name that is in B1. Sorry if this was not clear, you already provided me with a bunch of code, thanks for that!

Comment: @Wesley, I worked on the 2nd subfolder in the default folder. If targeting the fourth folder, "If UBound (vSplit) = 1 Then" to "If UBound (vSplit) = 3 Then" to "If InStr (vSplit (1), str) Then" to "If InStr (vSplit ( 3), str) Then ".   Replace the remaining vSplit (1) with vSplit (3).

Comment: I attached a picture in my original post to visualise the folder layout. The main folder will always be the same, the first subfolder is unknown, the second subfolder is known (call this range("B2") ). I can retrieve this name from some info upfront. Then for the third subfoldesr. In this level, you will find the folders matching the B1 name. There can be multiple folders that have this name and they all need to be copied. the 4th subfolders are 'nameless' but they just are copied within the 3th. There are no files with the B1 name in any of the folders.

Comment: So what the macro needs to do is loop through all first, second and third subfolders to find the matching B1 value and copy the folder to a destination. Hopefully this is somewhat clear because I think there is some miscommunication.The second subfolder is known so maybe this can make the loop a little bit smaller because there are a lot of folders in each level.

Comment: 1 more thing, the macro cannot loop the 4th (black) subfolders because within every folder here there are roughly 1000 other folders and images...

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I realy appreciate it! I accepted your answer because it is working om small folders. However the main folder has so much subfolder, excel crashes when trying to map all of them. I think it happens in the SearchSubFolder sub. How can I prevent that it will look inside the vSplit(2) folders? Because every vSplit(2) folder has a lot of subfolders on its own and this is the majority of folders actually. I tried to add an IF step `If sbFolder <> "*cnd" Then` but the wildcard will not work here probably? Still It would be better if it didn`t look inside the vSplit(2)

Comment: all the subfolders from the target vSplit(2) end with "_cnd"

Answer (score 0):

Previously, if you had to collect all the folders and then copy the folder that meets the conditions, this will collect only the folders that meet the conditions and then copy. This is more efficient.

```
Option Explicit

Dim vR()
Dim n As Long
Dim str As String
Sub copyFileFromFolder()

    Dim strFolder As String, TargetFolder As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vSplit
    Dim Path As String
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim FS As Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Set FS = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    strFolder = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\retrieve test\New folder\"
    TargetFolder = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\retrieve test\Lay\Lay\"

    '*** The folder address below is for my test.
    'strFolder = "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\"                 '<~~ for my test -->It corresponds to  your New folder
    'TargetFolder = "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\target\"       '<~~ for my test

    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    str = Wb.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B1")

    SearchFolder strFolder
    On Error Resume Next

    For i = 1 To n
        Path = vR(i)
        Path = Replace(Path, strFolder, "")
        vSplit = Split(Path, "\")

        FS.CopyFolder vR(i), TargetFolder & vSplit(2)
    Next i

    '** Show Root folder's subfolders

    With Sheets.Add ' set Sheets("your sheets's name)
        .UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents
        .Range("a2").Resize(n) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End With
    Erase vR
    n = 0
End Sub

Sub SearchFolder(strRoot As String)
    Dim FS As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fsFD As Folder
    Dim f As Folder
    Dim p As String
    Dim s As String
    Dim vSplit

    On Error Resume Next
    p = Application.PathSeparator
    If Right(strRoot, 1) = p Then
    Else
        strRoot = strRoot & p
    End If
    Set FS = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Set fsFD = FS.GetFolder(strRoot)
    For Each f In fsFD.SubFolders
        s = f.Path
        s = Replace(s, "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\retrieve test\New folder\", "")
        's = Replace(s, "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\", "")

        vSplit = Split(s, "\")
        If UBound(vSplit) = 2 Then
            If InStr(vSplit(2), str) Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
                vR(n) = f.Path
            End If
        End If
        SearchSubfolder f
    Next f

    Set fsFD = Nothing
    Set FS = Nothing

End Sub
Sub SearchSubfolder(objFolder As Folder)
    Dim sbFolder As Object
    Dim f As Folder
    Dim s As String
    Dim vSplit
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim str As String

    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    str = Wb.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B1")

    For Each sbFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        s = sbFolder.Path
        s = Replace(s, "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\retrieve test\New folder\", "")
        's = Replace(s, "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\", "")

        vSplit = Split(s, "\")
        If UBound(vSplit) > 2 Then Exit Sub
        SearchSubfolder sbFolder
        If UBound(vSplit) = 2 Then
            If InStr(vSplit(2), str) Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
                vR(n) = sbFolder.Path
            End If
        End If
    Next sbFolder

End Sub
```

Comment: The first code that you provides works fine, it searches for the 2020-02-str(B1)-1, 2 and 3 and copies there entire folders. This is indeed what needs to be done. But because the 3th sub in the code 'SearchSubFolder' will list ALL subfolders. It should not list the black (in the picture) subfolders because there are just to many.

Comment: There are more than 500 000 'black' folders so excel crashes when it is listing all these.

Comment: @Wesley, It's not a problem with Excel, it seems to be a problem with your computer's memory due to copying files. Usually, it seems to be a problem related to the problem because the time lag occurs when copying a large amount of files in the file explorer.

Comment: so it is not possible to exclude the last subfolder in the `for each sbFolder in objFolder.Subfolders`?

Comment: @Wesley, I knew your problem consciousness. I changed my answer.

Comment: This is indeed better but I see now that the looping is not correct. It loops: 4.1-A, 4.2-A, 5.1-A,5.2-A, 6.1-A,6.2-A and then instead of going to 4.1-B it continues 6.2-B, 6.3-C, 6.2-D, 6.2-E.

Comment: @Wesley, Here, only the third folder is collected, and other names can also be collected. The file was filtered out of the copyFileFromFolder () folder. If necessary, you only need to store the conditions in this folder.

Comment: the loop is still bugged. It still maps all the subfolders from 4.1 starting with A, then all the subfolders from 4.2 starting with A all subfolders from 5.1 starting with A, ... untill 6.2 and then it starts mapping only in 6.2 all the subfolders A B C D E F G H I,....