# Go through Path

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a problem: I want to build a tool that take information from .xlsm file. These Files are in subfolders. So I need to check all folders in that path and go into the subfolder "eingang". That subfolder includes many other folders where u can find the .xlsm files.
After that i need to safe some information like "last used" or created date of every file and print it on the worksheet.

So my idea was, to use a "do while" loop to check every mainfolder and check with a new "do while" loop for the subfolder "eingang" etc.

```
Public Function DateienSuchen(Optional Ordnerpfad As String = "S:\Transfercenter", _
                              Optional Dateityp As String, _
                              Optional OhneUnterordner As Boolean) As String()

   Dim idx         As Long
   Dim lngTyp      As Long
   Dim strDir      As String
   Dim strAktDir   As String
   Dim colDir      As New Collection
   Dim arrResult() As String
   lngTyp = Len(Dateityp)
   If Right$(Ordnerpfad, 1) <> "S:\Transfercenter" Then
      Ordnerpfad = Ordnerpfad & "S:\Transfercenter"
   End If
   colDir.Add Ordnerpfad
   Do While colDir.Count > 0
      strAktDir = colDir.Item(1)
      colDir.Remove 1
      strDir = Dir$(strAktDir, vbDirectory)
      Do While Len(strDir) > 0
         If (strDir <> ".") And (strDir <> "..") Then
                colDir.Add
         End If

         strDir = Dir$
      Loop
   Loop
    For Each strDir In colDir
      strAktDir = colDir.Item(1)
      colDir.Remove 1
      strAktDir = Dir$(strDir & "Eingang")
        Do While strAktDir <> ""

   Set colDir = Nothing
   DateienSuchen = arrResult
End Function
```

That was my idea to check every folder.

I hope you can help me. When u need more information, feel free to ask.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Does your script work? In order for people to help you better, we need to know specific issues you are having. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Use the `FileSystemObject` it will allow  you to loop through subfolders and get the file properties as last modified.

Comment: No it doesnt`t work like it shoud. And i also don´t have any idea how to safe these informations in an array. I´m new in VBA, that my first try. Thats why i have many issues :/

Comment: Refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60694689/fso-multiple-wildcards-for-folder-path/60698896#60698896) We need to write code that runs the subfolder and loops through the subfolders again. This can be done using a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

This is to show you the logic on how to print directly to your sheet some attributes for the files:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject 'You need the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library under tools-references
    Dim mainFolder As Folder: Set mainFolder = fso.GetFolder("Your main folder path")
    Dim SubFolder As Folder
    Dim myFile As File
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet name where you want to print")
    With ws
        Dim lrow As Long
        For Each SubFolder In mainFolder.SubFolders
            For Each myFile In SubFolder.Files
                If myFile.Type = "your filetype" Then
                    lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'next blank row in column A
                    .Cells(lrow, 1) = myFile.Name
                    .Cells(lrow, 2) = myFile.DateCreated
                    .Cells(lrow, 3) = myFile.DateLastModified
                    .Cells(lrow, 4) = myFile.DateLastAccessed
                    .Cells(lrow, 5) = myFile.Size
                End If
            Next myFile
        Next SubFolder
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: ah ok thanks. I know what u want to show me but the problem ist that i don´t search for a specific filename.

Comment: @MaximilianMerckens this doesn't either it looks for specific extension like your code. You can change `"your filetype"` for `"*.xlsm"` so it will give you info about all the xlsm files in the subfolders.